# Spacing problems (overlap) with DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: unicode-math, mathtools

I'm have a defined a couple of math delimiters via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, however, they seem to create some problems with respect to the spacing with some fonts. For example the following codes yields an overlap between the P and the left bracket.

[image]

Is there a way to fix the definition of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` such that I can use it right away in all my documents?

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,xparse}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens{\lparen}{\rparen}

\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\parens*{#1}}
\newcommand{\powersetlr}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \powerset{XX}\\
        \powersetlr{XX}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may have come across a kerning error (bug?) in the `XITS Math` font family. I suggest you switch to the Stix Two Math font (available online [here](http://stixfonts.org/)). No such kerning problems with the Stix Two text and math fonts...

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with XeLaTeX. With LuaLaTeX it's a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can at all switch from the `XITS` math font to the `Stix Two` math font, the kerning problems are removed automatically. The `Stix Two` text and math fonts are not distributed automatically with TeXlive, but they may be downloaded free of charge from stixfonts.org.

[image]

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,mleftright,unicode-math} 
% "Stix Two" text and math fonts: see http://stixfonts.org/
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[math-style=ISO,StylisticSet=1]

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens()
\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\parens*{#1}}
\newcommand{\powersetlr}[1]{\mathcal{P}\mleft(#1\mright)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &\mathcal{P}(XX)\\
        &\mathcal{P}\parens{XX}\\
        &\powerset{XX}\\
        &\powersetlr{XX}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With LuaLaTeX there's a different treatment of italic correction. You can restore the “old” one (which LaTeX expects) by adding `\mathoption old 1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,xparse}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens{\lparen}{\rparen}

\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\/\parens*{#1}}
\newcommand{\powersetlr}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}

\mathoption old 1

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \powerset{XX}\\
        \powersetlr{XX}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can define `\powerset` with the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` which allows for a  `pre-code` and a `post-code` before and after the delimiters.

This code works well with `xelatex`, not so well with `lualatex`, perhaps due to the kerning problem mentioned by @Mico:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,xparse}%
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
 \setmathfont{XITS Math}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\powerset[1]{\mathcal{P}}\lparen\rparen{}{#1}
\newcommand{\powersetlr}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        \powerset*{X^{X^2}}\\
        \powersetlr{XX}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

With `xelatex`:

[image]

With `lualatex`:

[image]